# What is /home/bitnami/stack/ directory for on Bitnami NGINX Open Source image?

Tags: nginx, bitnami

What is `/home/bitnami/stack/` directory used for on Bitnami NGINX Open Source image? For example, the documentation says to edit `/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` for the default Nginx config. But then there is a bunch of Nginx configuration hanging out in  `/home/bitnami/stack/nginx` If you make changes in one, it gets updated in the other but they don't appear to be symlinks.

If it makes any difference this is on a VPS created through AWS Lightsail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main Nginx configuration file is set in `/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`. All other `*.config` files that you see loaded, are referenced inside the `nginx.conf` file.

Take a look at the snippet from the file. Notice the lines that start with `include`:

```
include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/*.conf";

# HTTP Server
server {
    # Port to listen on, can also be set in IP:PORT format
    listen  80;

    include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/*.conf";

    location /status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }
}
```